# How does Saturn's ring rain fit with the earlier "big empty" results?

Tags: saturn, planetary-ring, cassini, saturn-rings

In 2017, the results from Cassini's flight through the region between Saturn and the inner edge of the rings [were described as the "Big Empty"](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=6832). Nevertheless in 2018, the region was described as having [a huge amount of "ring rain" consisting of dust grains coated in ices and organics](https://phys.org/news/2018-10-chemical-complexity-saturn-planet-upper.html) falling into the atmosphere.

How can these be reconciled? Was the earlier determination of the conditions in error, is this a consequence of variability or sampling different types of particles, or something else?